# White screen and missing file warning, prestashop or apache?

Tags: apache, file, prestashop

Sometimes and sporadically, when I navigate on my back office I receive a white screen and warning of "missing file".

I do not know if it's apache or prestashop problem. I have searched everywhere, without success.

Any ideas?

Missing file prestashop or apache:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It shall be an Apache problem :
 - I assume index.php really exists. It's the root of Prestashop after all.
 - Routes are created by their controller name.
 - I assume you have also in your installation controllers/admin/AdminDashboardController.php

So regenerating Apache configuration in the SEO & URLs menu should do the job :).

Answer (score 0):

strangle problem, but may be it is php problem , please try to fix it following link :
https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/prestashop-16/blank-screen

Answer (score 0):

this problem may be due to your (files & folders) permissions. i already had this problem